# JButton query in Belisha Beacon Program

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Basically my Belisha Beacon has to stay Orange when I click on the Steady button but in my Program when I click the Steady Button, the Beacon stays as Light Grey instead. Can someone please identify where I am going wrong please? Thank you much :). Here is my code:

```
package Homework;


import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class BelishaBeacon {
    private static Timer timer;
    public class Drawing extends JPanel {

        private int x = 125;
        private int y = 80;
        private boolean changeColors = false;


        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

            Rectangle box1 = new Rectangle(165, 180, 20, 45);
            Rectangle box2 = new Rectangle(165, 225, 20, 45);
            Rectangle box3 = new Rectangle(165, 270, 20, 45);
            Rectangle box4 = new Rectangle(165, 315, 20, 45);
            Rectangle box5 = new Rectangle(165, 360, 20, 45);
            Rectangle box6 = new Rectangle(165, 405, 20, 45);


            Ellipse2D.Double ball = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, 100, 100);
            g2.draw(ball);
            g2.draw(box1);
            g2.draw(box2);
            g2.draw(box3);
            g2.draw(box4);
            g2.draw(box5);
            g2.draw(box6);

            g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2.fill(box1);
            g2.fill(box3);
            g2.fill(box5);
            g2.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
            g2.fill(ball);
            changeColors = !changeColors;
            if (changeColors) {
                g2.setColor(Color.lightGray);
                g2.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, 100, 100));
            }
        }




        public void changeColors() {
            changeColors = true;
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public BelishaBeacon() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(350, 570);
        frame.setTitle("Belisha Beacon");
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        final Drawing shapes = new Drawing();

        timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                shapes.repaint();
            }
        });



        JButton jbtFlash = new JButton("Flash");
        jbtFlash.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Flashing");
                if (!timer.isRunning()) {
                    timer.start();
                }

            }
        });




        final JButton jbtSteady = new JButton("Steady");
        jbtSteady.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                        timer.stop();
                    }
                });


        JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel();
        controlPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2, 0, 0));
        controlPanel.add(jbtFlash);
        controlPanel.add(jbtSteady);

        frame.add(controlPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.add(shapes);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new BelishaBeacon();
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly same as this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36651192/jbutton-query-in-belisha-beacon-program. Are you by any chance a twin of Federer?

Comment: You probably could use the hint I left for Federer :)

Comment: @bili me and him are in the same class aha and both me and him have tried that but got no where :(.

Comment: Perhaps you can share what you and him have tried? Don't want to miss the submission date for your homework now, do you? :)

Comment: Oooo I'l update the question :). Yeah I have to make sure I'm on time aha.

Comment: final JButton jbtSteady = new JButton("Steady");
        jbtSteady.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                     if (Color.Orange);
                        timer.stop();
                    }
                });

Comment: I added if the color is orange in the steady button method but I don't think that is logical.

Comment: That's one step forward. This leads to next question how can you check the current colour of the ball is orange?

Comment: It is working now :), thank you so much mate :).

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
public class BelishaBeacon {
    private static Timer timer;
    public class Drawing extends JPanel {

        private int x = 125;
        private int y = 80;
        private boolean changeColors = false;


        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

            Rectangle box1 = new Rectangle(165, 180, 20, 45);
            Rectangle box2 = new Rectangle(165, 225, 20, 45);
            Rectangle box3 = new Rectangle(165, 270, 20, 45);
            Rectangle box4 = new Rectangle(165, 315, 20, 45);
            Rectangle box5 = new Rectangle(165, 360, 20, 45);
            Rectangle box6 = new Rectangle(165, 405, 20, 45);


            Ellipse2D.Double ball = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, 100, 100);
            g2.draw(ball);
            g2.draw(box1);
            g2.draw(box2);
            g2.draw(box3);
            g2.draw(box4);
            g2.draw(box5);
            g2.draw(box6);

            g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2.fill(box1);
            g2.fill(box3);
            g2.fill(box5);
            g2.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
            g2.fill(ball);
           // changeColors = !changeColors;
            if (changeColors) {
                g2.setColor(Color.lightGray);
                g2.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, 100, 100));
            }
        }




        public void changeColors() {
            changeColors = !changeColors;
            repaint();
        }

        public boolean getChangeColors() {
            return changeColors;
        }
    }

    public BelishaBeacon() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(350, 570);
        frame.setTitle("Belisha Beacon");
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        final Drawing shapes = new Drawing();

        timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //shapes.repaint();
                shapes.changeColors();
            }
        });



        JButton jbtFlash = new JButton("Flash");
        jbtFlash.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Flashing");
                if (!timer.isRunning()) {
                    timer.start();
                }

            }
        });




        final JButton jbtSteady = new JButton("Steady");
        jbtSteady.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                        timer.stop();
                        if(shapes.getChangeColors()) {
                            shapes.changeColors();
                        }
                    }
                });


        JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel();
        controlPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2, 0, 0));
        controlPanel.add(jbtFlash);
        controlPanel.add(jbtSteady);

        frame.add(controlPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.add(shapes);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new BelishaBeacon();
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that but I need the Beacon to be Flashing before hand and only when I click the steady button it to be orange and when I click the flash button again it has to flash again .

Comment: I just tried it now and it works. Oh my thank you so much for your help :).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to *toggle* the color in `paintComponent()`, give `Drawing` a  `Color` and use it to render the ball:

```
private Color color = Color.lightGray;

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        …
        g2.setColor(color);
        g2.fill(ball);
        …
    }
```

Make `changeColors()` actually change colors:

```
    public void changeColors() {
        if (Color.orange.equals(color)) {
            color = Color.lightGray;
        } else {
            color = Color.orange;
        }
        repaint();
    }
```

And add a `makeSteady()` method:

```
public void makeSteady() {
    color = Color.orange;
    repaint();
}
```

Now, your timer's action can just do `shapes.changeColors()`, your <kbd>Flash</kbd> button handler can just do `timer.restart()` and your <kbd>Steady</kbd> button handler can just do this:

```
timer.stop();
shapes.makeSteady();
```

Also, don't forget to [`invokeLater()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).